# Is there a way to convert apps into menu bar apps hidden from the dock?

Tags: dock, menu-bar, application-switcher

I have a number of apps that I run daily in the background (e.g. midipipe for using a midi controller to control my computer, and a pomadoro productivity app).  I would like these apps to appear in my top menubar, where many other apps live that are hidden from the command+tab app switcher (screen shot included).  Is there a way to place an app up here and hide it from the app switcher?  I'm aware of the info.plist hack to hide apps from the app switcher, but I'm looking for a different kind of solution [image: menubar screen shot]

Comment: It's not possible without third-party apps. From your description I assume that you want to reduce the amount of icons on your dock and move them to the top menu bar. Did you consider another solution - why not to group icons you want to move into one folder and leave them in the dock? They all will be represented by one icon where after clicking a list will appear. Saves a lot of space. I group all my dev. apps and gfx. apps using this pattern. Dock still contains all I need but looks cleaner...

Comment: eh, yeah, thanks I *could* do that... it just seemed like it would be really slick to be able to pick and choose how I access my apps, but so far it doesn't seem like there is a straightforward solution.